# (Athena/Presto) Window function (lag) is not reading the previous lag row

Tags: window-functions, amazon-presto

I have two tables, `credit_memos` and `credit_memo_items` and want to show each event individually and will thus do a insert (doing union in this case which is logically the same).

I know the key for both tables and am doing a union with them while sharing the same partition key `credit_memo_dd` that I'll be using for the window.

I'm trying to use lag to fill up the rest of the null rows as shown.

[image]

The code for the second column looks as follows:

`coalesce(invoice_nk, lag(invoice_nk, 1, '') over (partition by cm_dd order by event_at)) as invoice_nk`

For some reason the third row shown in the picture is not able to interpret the previous lagged row and insert a value its row as a result. I presume it may have to do something where Athena does not actually execute the lag function recursively and takes the previous row in each partition literally and doesn't wait for the previous rows to get executed.

Is there a way to grab values recursively as I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Update:

Here's the full query:

```
with
  cme as(
    with
      cm as(
        select
    --      change_log
          row_number() over (partition by id order by updated_at desc) r
        , cast(cm.invoice_id as varchar(99))                         as invoice_nk
        , cast(cm.id as varchar(99))                                 as cm_dd
        , cast(cm.created_at as timestamp)                           as cm_created_at
        , cast(cm.updated_at as timestamp)                           as cm_updated_at
        from "postgres-replica-parquet".credit_memos cm
      )
    select
      case when r = 1 then cm_created_at
           else cm_updated_at end as cm_begin_at
    , null as cmi_begin_at
    , invoice_nk
    , cm_dd
    , cm_created_at
    , cm_updated_at
    from cm
  )
, cmi as(
    with
      ci as(
        select
    --      ci.change_log
          row_number() over (partition by id order by updated_at desc) r
        , cast(ci.credit_memo_id as varchar(99)) as cm_id
        , cast(ci.created_at as timestamp)       as cmi_created_at
        , cast(ci.updated_at as timestamp)       as cmi_updated_at
        from "postgres-replica-parquet".credit_memo_items ci
      )
    select -- row 1 is the snapshot when cdc first started
      null as cm_begin_at
    , case when r = 1 then cmi_created_at
           else cmi_updated_at end as cmi_begin_at
    , null as invoice_nk
    , cm_id as cm_dd
    , null as cm_created_at
    , null as cm_updated_at
    from ci
  )
, combined as(
    with
      all as(
        select * from cme
        union select * from cmi
      )
    select
      greatest(
        coalesce(cm_begin_at, cast(date_parse('1970-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') as timestamp))
      , coalesce(cmi_begin_at, cast(date_parse('1970-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') as timestamp))
      ) as event_at
    , *
    from all
  )
select
  event_at
, cm_begin_at as event_credit_memo_last_at
, cmi_begin_at as event_credit_memo_item_last_at
, coalesce(invoice_nk, lag(invoice_nk, 1, '') over (partition by cm_dd order by event_at)) as invoice_nk
, cm_dd as credit_memo_dd
from combined
```

And a snapshot of the full result:

[image]

Rows 3 and 12 should have the invoice_nk based on the credit_memo

cm is the subquery to grab the credit memos

cmi is the subquery to grab the credit memo items

combined is just to precompute the order by key in the window functions

Note that both are pulled from a database that has the full change log (CDC).

The end goal is to make one row for each event, I'm defining an event for the final table to be any time either credit memo or credit memo item undergoes a change. I would like to be able to snapshot the state of a credit memo combined with the credit memo item by windowing at the `event_at` for reporting.

Comment: providing tables schemas, sample data, and full query will get you better help. your window functions works correctly in SQL server ( all i have) but that may be more complexities to your query that is resulting in your issue or it may be an athena issue. grasping at straws, but maybe try order by coalesce(cm_date,cmi_date) instead of event_at

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the `LAG` window function is working exactly as intended in your query - you should probably be instead using a `FIRST_VALUE` window function for the task you appear to be trying to accomplish... but more on that later.

Screenshots are not typically considered sample data, but I've gone ahead and fabricated some schema elements and sample data from what you did provide.  Nobody who isn't as bored as I currently am will do this, so in the future it would help you to do a similar thing as below yourself.

```
IF ( OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb.dbo.#t_CreditMemo', 'U' ) IS NULL )
BEGIN
    --DROP TABLE #t_CreditMemo;
    CREATE TABLE #t_CreditMemo
    (
        CreditMemo_PK               BIGINT IDENTITY( 1, 1 ) NOT NULL,
        InvoiceID                   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        CreditMemoID                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        DateCreated                 DATETIME,
        DateUpdated                 DATETIME
    );

    INSERT  INTO #t_CreditMemo ( InvoiceID, CreditMemoID, DateCreated, DateUpdated )
    VALUES  ( '08797CA7-F843-4964-8D8F-46E41A2F232B', '15F6FEBB-0B43-4CD0-880D-8F703A2C0692', 
                '2022-01-28 15:13:33.757', '2022-01-28 15:13:33.757' ),
            ( '0D9A6C3D-987E-42A3-B59E-55551822F650', '06A31D99-9075-493C-8532-A5FCE090F167', 
                '2020-08-28 16:42:56.627', '2020-08-28 16:42:56.627' ),
            ( 'DFDF1A21-2D0A-4826-9C76-78680C4CA0D9', '20AE5822-5846-4EE6-A512-A61EB427BC72', 
                '2020-06-25 21:15:05.273', '2020-06-25 21:15:05.273' ),
            ( '36C39B5A-D18C-4DD6-9B5E-88DC203C5E7B', '1FDCFEDD-0A3A-40A7-A2AF-F435F0486134', 
                '2021-02-12 20:26:04.780', '2021-02-12 20:26:04.780' ),
            ( '45CED7BB-63F4-4A9D-A5EB-9BFD18332E32', '04A450EE-8C3D-4573-9274-C63F82EFFEC8', 
                '2021-06-16 21:07:19.770', '2021-06-16 21:07:19.770' ),
            ( '70452702-0592-4262-BF08-C8C88B4BC27B', '20BDCDEE-93E9-47F4-AE5B-B8D98D404680', 
                '2020-05-18 20:15:19.000', '2020-05-18 20:15:19.000' );
END;

IF ( OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb.dbo.#t_CreditMemoItem', 'U' ) IS NULL )
BEGIN
    --DROP TABLE #t_CreditMemoItem;
    CREATE TABLE #t_CreditMemoItem
    (
        CreditMemo_PK               BIGINT IDENTITY( 1, 1 ) NOT NULL,
        CreditMemoID                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        CreditMemoItemID            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        DateCreated                 DATETIME,
        DateUpdated                 DATETIME
    );

    INSERT  INTO #t_CreditMemoItem ( CreditMemoID, CreditMemoItemID, DateCreated, DateUpdated )
    VALUES  ( '15F6FEBB-0B43-4CD0-880D-8F703A2C0692', NEWID(), 
                '2022-01-28 15:13:33.767', '2022-01-28 15:13:33.767' ),
            ( '06A31D99-9075-493C-8532-A5FCE090F167', NEWID(), 
                '2020-08-28 16:42:56.633', '2020-08-28 16:42:56.633' ),
            ( '20AE5822-5846-4EE6-A512-A61EB427BC72', NEWID(), 
                '2020-06-25 21:15:05.280', '2020-06-25 21:15:05.280' ),
            ( '20AE5822-5846-4EE6-A512-A61EB427BC72', NEWID(), 
                '2020-06-25 21:15:05.283', '2020-06-25 21:15:05.283' ),
            ( '04A450EE-8C3D-4573-9274-C63F82EFFEC8', NEWID(), 
                '2021-06-16 21:07:19.773', '2021-06-16 21:07:19.773' ),
            ( '04A450EE-8C3D-4573-9274-C63F82EFFEC8', NEWID(),
                '2021-06-16 21:07:19.777', '2021-06-16 21:07:19.777' ),
            ( '1FDCFEDD-0A3A-40A7-A2AF-F435F0486134', NEWID(), 
                '2021-02-12 20:26:04.787', '2021-02-12 20:26:04.787' );
END;
```

Then you can review the differences in the output the window functions provide:

```
;WITH   
cte_CreditMemo AS (
    SELECT  Ordinal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (   PARTITION BY CreditMemoID
                                            ORDER BY DateUpdated DESC ),
            InvoiceID, CreditMemoID, DateCreated, DateUpdated
    FROM    #t_CreditMemo ),
cte_CreditMemoEvent AS (
    SELECT  DateCreditMemoBegin = CASE
                    WHEN Ordinal = 1 
                      THEN DateCreated
                    ELSE DateUpdated
                END,
            DateCreditMemoItemBegin = NULL,
            InvoiceID, CreditMemoID, DateCreated, DateUpdated
    FROM    cte_CreditMemo ),
cte_CreditMemoItem AS (
    SELECT  Ordinal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (   PARTITION BY CreditMemoItemID
                                            ORDER BY DateUpdated DESC ),
            CreditMemoID, CreditMemoItemID, DateCreated, DateUpdated 
    FROM    #t_CreditMemoItem ),
cte_CreditMemoItemEvent AS (
    SELECT  DateCreditMemoBegin = NULL,
            DateCreditMemoItemBegin = CASE
                    WHEN Ordinal = 1 
                      THEN DateCreated
                    ELSE DateUpdated
                END,
            InvoiceID = NULL,
            CreditMemoID, CreditMemoItemID, DateCreated, DateUpdated 
    FROM    cte_CreditMemoItem ),
cte_All AS (
    SELECT  DateCreditMemoBegin, DateCreditMemoItemBegin,
            InvoiceID, CreditMemoID, CreditMemoItemID = NULL
    FROM    cte_CreditMemoEvent
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DateCreditMemoBegin, DateCreditMemoItemBegin,
            InvoiceID, CreditMemoID, CreditMemoItemID
    FROM    cte_CreditMemoItemEvent ),
cte_Combined AS (
    SELECT  DateEvent = GREATEST( DateCreditMemoBegin, DateCreditMemoItemBegin ),
            DateCreditMemoBegin, DateCreditMemoItemBegin,
            InvoiceID, CreditMemoID, CreditMemoItemID
    FROM    cte_All )
SELECT  DateEvent,
        DateCreditMemoBegin,
        DateCreditMemoItemBegin,
        InvoiceID = COALESCE( InvoiceID, LAG( InvoiceID, 1, NULL ) OVER (   PARTITION BY CreditMemoID
                                                                            ORDER BY DateEvent ) ),
        InvoiceID = FIRST_VALUE( InvoiceID ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CreditMemoID 
                                                    ORDER BY DateEvent ),
        CreditMemoID, CreditMemoItemID
FROM    cte_Combined
ORDER BY CreditMemoID, DateEvent;
```

As you can see from the results of the above query, the `FIRST_VALUE` window function will fill the `InvoiceID` column as you have described is intended, whereas the `LAG` window function does indeed lag the results from the previous row, producing `NULL`s when the previous column value is `NULL`.  This is because database operations are generally intended to be set-based operations - there is no recursion happening here.

It also may be worth pointing out the solution you're working on appears to be massive overkill for the problem, which very likely has a much simpler solution.

```
SELECT  DateEvent = GREATEST( cm.DateCreated, cm.DateUpdated, e.DateCreated, e.DateUpdated ),
        cm.InvoiceID, e.CreditMemoID, e.CreditMemoItemID
FROM (  SELECT  CreditMemoID, CreditMemoItemID = NULL,
                DateCreated, DateUpdated
        FROM    #t_CreditMemo
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  CreditMemoID, CreditMemoItemID,
                DateCreated, DateUpdated
        FROM    #t_CreditMemoItem ) e
INNER JOIN #t_CreditMemo cm
    ON  e.CreditMemoID = cm.CreditMemoID
ORDER BY e.CreditMemoID, DateEvent;
```

Comment: Okay that helps a lot. I'll make sure to have better information in my questions next time.